# Discord.py command cooldown

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord.py bot and that bot will have the command "revive." That command will send 2 pings to revive the chat. I have set it that only the person with MENTION EVERYONE permission will only be able to use the command but when members use the command the cooldown starts. So is there a way to make it so members don't affect the cooldown?

````
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1.0, 3600.0, commands.BucketType.guild) 
async def revive(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.mention_everyone:
        await ctx.send(
            "I shall revive the CHAT, <@800171737832226827> <@&800168050077728808>"
        )
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=None,
                              decription=None,
                              color=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.add_field(
            name="Error!",
            value=
            "You do not have the permissions to do this! You need the permission: **Mention Everyone**"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: We're having a really tough time understand your question, if you don't want a cooldown why don't you simply remove the decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It triggers the cooldown because when normal members use the function it actually enters the function and starts doing what is coded in there.

What you need to do to avoid triggering the cooldown is adding a check to ensure that the user calling the command has the right permissions, but passing this as a decorator, which is evaluated before the function is actually run, as it *decorates* it.

In this case you will need to add `@commands.has_permissions(mention_everyone=True)` to your code.

It should look like this:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(mention_everyone=True)
@commands.cooldown(1.0, 3600.0, commands.BucketType.guild) 
async def revive(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "I shall revive the CHAT, <@800171737832226827> <@&800168050077728808>"
    )
```